# Calculating maximum allowable velocity of an object during holography

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics, hologram

I am working through some questions in preparation for an upcoming exam and the following has me doubting myself:

*An experiment takes $x$ seconds to create a hologram of an object using $\lambda$ nm laser light. Estimate the maximum allowable velocity of the object.*

My initial thought was that if the object moves by more than half a wavelength in the exposure time then the image would become blurred but this argument seems too trivial. Is there something I am missing? Is there someway to relate this to visibility without being given more information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on the setup and the direction of motion, but your intuition is pretty close to correct.  However, it might be a good idea to consider a worst-case situation: the object is illuminated from very near the recording plate and is moving directly toward the recording plate.  In that case, if the object moves just a quarter wavelength during the exposure, the phase shift of light reflected to the plate by the object will be 180 degrees, so a quarter wavelength motion during the exposure will be too much.  Phase shift of ~ 10 degrees during the exposure is sometimes considered acceptable in some circumstances.